# Can true damage dealt be amplified by the mastery Double-Edged Sword?

Tags: league-of-legends

Irelia does 75 true damage with W (Hiten Style at max lvl) activated.

If I get the mastery of Double-Edged Sword, will this amplify W's true damage as well?

Comment: No.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Double-Edged_Sword_(Season_Four_Mastery)

Comment: Easiest way to test this is with olafs e. You will see it only does the damage it says, exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

Any form of true damage deals a fixed amount of damage that cannot be reduced or amplified. This basically means that the only way of increasing irelias True-Damage output is buying attackspeed since the damage doesn't scale with anything directly.